# build javascript object array failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to produce this

```
arr = [{
    "name": "john",
    "tel": 123
}, {
    "name": "marry",
    "tel": 999
}];
```

but what I got with below code is just single array.

```
var arr = [{}];

$('button').click(function () {
    $.each($('.row'), function () {
        arr.name = $(this).find('li.name input').val();
        arr.tell = $(this).find('li.tel input').val();
    });

    console.log(arr);
});
```

What's wrong with it?
http://jsfiddle.net/1LLwh15f/1/

Answer (score 1):

All you're doing in your code is assigning to the same two properties on the array instance over and over. You're not doing anything to either create the objects you've said you want in your array, or to add any entries to the array.

To add things to the array, you can use [`Array#push`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7). To create objects you can use an [object initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5).

```
$.each($('.row'), function () {
    arr.push({
        name: $(this).find('li.name input').val(),
        tell: $(this).find('li.tel input').val()
    });
});
```

Alternately, you can use jQuery's `map` function:

```
arr = $('.row').map(function() {
    return {
        name: $(this).find('li.name input').val(),
        tell: $(this).find('li.tel input').val()
    };
}).get(); // <== Note the .get() at the end
```

---

Side note: Your initialization:

```
var arr = [{}];
```

...creates an array with one blank object in it. You don't need the blank object, just `= []` is all you need to create an array.

Comment: Just curious: why did you link to the ecma-international definition, instead of a more user-friendly documentation like MDN?

Comment: @Cerbrus: In general, I prefer primary sources. That's almost certainly going to change, though -- the ES6 specification is **ridiculously** hard to read.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It doesn't appear that much worse for [`Array#push`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.push) yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing obj just you are overriding again and again, If you want desire output do this

```
var arr = [];

$('button').click(function(){
   $.each($('.row'), function(){
       var obj={};
    obj.name = $(this).find('li.name input').val();
    obj.tell = $(this).find('li.tel input').val();
       arr.push(obj)
});

console.log(arr);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1LLwh15f/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to `push` into array. This will add new object in the array at the end.

```
var arr = [];
// Remove {} from array declaration

$('button').click(function () {
    $('.row').each(function () {
        // push object inside array
        arr.push({
            name: $(this).find('li.name input').val(),
            tell: $(this).find('li.tel input').val()
        });
    });

    console.log(arr);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1LLwh15f/2/

Answer (score 1):

You're adding data to the array incorrectly.

Try this instead:

```js
var arr = []; // Don't add the empty object there.

$('button').click(function () {
    $.each($('.row'), function () {
        arr.push({
            name: $(this).find('li.name input').val(),
            tell: $(this).find('li.tel input').val()
        }); // Add a new element to the array, containing the current row's data.
    });

    console.log(arr);
    alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <li class="name"><input value="" placeholder="name" /></li>
    <li class="tel"><input value="" placeholder="tel" /></li>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <li class="name"><input value="" placeholder="name" /></li>
    <li class="tel"><input value="" placeholder="tel" /></li>
</div>
<br>
<button>submit</button>
```

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) Actually adds a new element to the end of the array, instead of what you were doing, which was adding `name` and `tell` properties to the array object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push values in array not to use it as object

```
var temp = {
    name: $(this).find('li.name input').val(),
    temp: $(this).find('li.tel input').val()
}

arr.push(temp);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvzukj47/